# How do I build my own handwritten digits dataset

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, dataset, classification, tensorflow-datasets

I have a set of images of numbers that go from 0 to 20 with intermediate classes(0,25 / 0,5 / 0,75). Each number will be defined as a class of its own. I have 22 images per class.

These images will be used for training and testing on a convolutional neural network for classification. I'm not worried about accuracy, it's only a proof of concept so I realise that the dataset is too small for any real reliable outcome. Like I said, it's only meant as a proof of concept.

**EDIT:** As suggested by @Kaveh, I checked out `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory`

As far as I could tell, this is used to increase your dataset size using data augmentation. However, what I'm asking is, now that I have these images set in different folders (22 images per folder, each folder making a class) how do I use them. I've always been loading one file that makes up the dataset (example: mnist; through keras). I've never used my own data and therefore, have no idea what the next step is.

Comment: The best way to use your images on the HDD, is using ``ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory``. It will create a dataset for you, and separate them in classes based on their folder. Check it out for more info: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

organize your directories as shown below

```
data_dir
-----train_dir
---------zero_dir
-------------first_zero_image.jpg
-------------sencond_zero_image,jpg
...
-------------twenty_second_zero_image.jpg
---------ones_dir
-------------first_ones_image.jpg
-------------second_one_image.jpg
...
-------------twenty_second_ones_image.jpg
......
         twenty_dir
-------------first_20_image.jpg
-------------seccond_20_image.jpg
...
-------------twenty_second_20_image.jpg
-----test_dir
--------zeros_dir
#  structure the test directory like the train directory and put
# your test images in it
```

Now you can use the Keras ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory to provide the data for model.fit.

```
train_path=os.path.join(data_dir, train_dir)
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
gen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255, validation_split=.2)
train_gen=gen.flow_from_directory( train_path,
                                   target_size=(256, 256),
                                   color_mode="rgb",
                                   classes=None,
                                   class_mode="categorical",
                                   batch_size=32,
                                   shuffle=True,
                                   seed=123,    
                                   subset='training' )  
valid_gen=gen.flow_from_directory( train_path,
                                   target_size=(256, 256),
                                   color_mode="rgb",
                                   classes=None,
                                   class_mode="categorical",
                                   batch_size=32,                                   
                                   shuffle=False, 
                                   subset='validation' )
history=model.fit(train_gen, epochs=20, validation_data=valid_gen)
```

That should do it